# Set image background to an existing slide apache poi ppt

Tags: java, apache-poi, backend, powerpoint, slide

I am trying to set image as a background to an specific slide that already exists (with blank background) and has some components (texts and images), but getting an error when opening the ppt created using apache poi. This is the ppt reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77g7W.png)

My code was based on another stackoverflow response but getting error

```java
XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("test.pptx"));
byte[] picData = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("image.jpg"));
XSLFPictureData pcData = slideShow.getSlides().get(0).getSlideShow().addPicture(picData, PictureData.PictureType.JPEG);
CTBackgroundProperties backgroundProperties = slideShow.getSlides().get(0).getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg().addNewBgPr();
CTBlipFillProperties blipFillProperties = backgroundProperties.addNewBlipFill();
CTRelativeRect ctRelativeRect = blipFillProperties.addNewStretch().addNewFillRect();
String idx = slideShow.getSlides().get(0).addRelation(null, XSLFRelation.IMAGES, pcData).getRelationship().getId();
CTBlip blib = blipFillProperties.addNewBlip();
blib.setEmbed(idx);

try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.pptx")) {
    slideShow.write(fileOut);
}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AxelRichter do you know maybe why I am not able to set the background for slide 0? or should I do it in another way? . Thanks.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post details of the error you claim to be getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
CTBackgroundProperties backgroundProperties = slideShow.getSlides().get(0).getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg().addNewBgPr();
```

always adds a new background (`Bg`) to the slide. That's fine with a new created slide. But an existent slide may have a background setting already. And then, after that code line, it would have two  background settings. That is not allowed.

So if the requirement is to change the background setting of an existent slide, then one should at first unset the old background setting before adding a new one.

In your case:

```
...
  if (slideShow.getSlides().get(0).getXmlObject().getCSld().isSetBg()) {
      slideShow.getSlides().get(0).getXmlObject().getCSld().unsetBg();
  }
  CTBackgroundProperties backgroundProperties = slideShow.getSlides().get(0).getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg().addNewBgPr();
...
```